# How does the exponential backoff configured in Google Pub/Sub's RetryPolicy work?

Tags: go, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, exponential-backoff

The `cloud.google.com/go/pubsub` library recently released (in v1.5.0, cf. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/releases/tag/pubsub%2Fv1.5.0) support for a new `RetryPolicy` server-side feature. The documentation (https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#RetryPolicy) for this currently reads

[image]

I've read the Wikipedia article, and although it describes exponential backoff in discrete time, I don't see how the article relates to the `MinimumBackoff` and `MaximumBackoff` parameters specifically. For guidance on this, I referred to the documentation for `github.com/cenkalti/backoff`, https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4?tab=doc#ExponentialBackOff. That library defines an `ExponentialBackoff` as

```golang
type ExponentialBackOff struct {
    InitialInterval     time.Duration
    RandomizationFactor float64
    Multiplier          float64
    MaxInterval         time.Duration
    // After MaxElapsedTime the ExponentialBackOff returns Stop.
    // It never stops if MaxElapsedTime == 0.
    MaxElapsedTime time.Duration
    Stop           time.Duration
    Clock          Clock
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

where each randomized interval is calculated as

```
randomized interval =
    RetryInterval * (random value in range [1 - RandomizationFactor, 1 + RandomizationFactor])
```

where `RetryInterval` is the current retry interval which, as I understand it, starts at a value of `InitialInterval` and is capped by `MaxInterval`.

Do I understand correctly that the `MinimumBackoff` and `MaximumBackoff` correspond to the `InitialInterval` and `MaxInterval` in `github.com/cenkalti/backoff`? That is, the `MinimumBackoff` is the initial wait period, and the `MaximumBackoff` is the largest amount of time allowed between retries?

To test my theories, I wrote the following simplified program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

var (
    projectID                      string
    minimumBackoff, maximumBackoff time.Duration
)

const (
    topicName             = "test-topic"
    subName               = "test-subscription"
    defaultMinimumBackoff = 10 * time.Second
    defaultMaximumBackoff = 10 * time.Minute
)

func main() {
    flag.StringVar(&projectID, "projectID", "my-project", "Google Project ID")
    flag.DurationVar(&minimumBackoff, "minimumBackoff", 5*time.Second, "minimum backoff")
    flag.DurationVar(&maximumBackoff, "maximumBackoff", 60*time.Second, "maximum backoff")
    flag.Parse()
    log.Printf("Running with minumum backoff %v and maximum backoff %v...", minimumBackoff, maximumBackoff)

    retryPolicy := &pubsub.RetryPolicy{MinimumBackoff: minimumBackoff, MaximumBackoff: maximumBackoff}

    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(context.Background(), projectID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("NewClient: %v", err)
    }

    topic, err := client.CreateTopic(context.Background(), topicName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateTopic: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Created topic %q", topicName)
    defer func() {
        topic.Stop()
        if err := topic.Delete(context.Background()); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Delete topic: %v", err)
        }
        log.Printf("Deleted topic %s", topicName)
    }()

    sub, err := client.CreateSubscription(context.Background(), subName, pubsub.SubscriptionConfig{
        Topic:       topic,
        RetryPolicy: retryPolicy,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateSubscription: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Created subscription %q", subName)
    defer func() {
        if err := sub.Delete(context.Background()); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Delete subscription: %v", err)
        }
        log.Printf("Deleted subscription %q", subName)
    }()

    go func() {
        sub.Receive(context.Background(), func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
            log.Printf("Nacking message: %s", msg.Data)
            msg.Nack()
        })
    }()

    topic.Publish(context.Background(), &pubsub.Message{Data: []byte("Hello, world!")})
    log.Println("Published message")
    time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
}
```

If I run it with the flag-default `MinimumBackoff` and `MaximumBackoff` of 5s and 60s, respectively, I get the following output:

```
> go run main.go
2020/07/29 18:49:32 Running with minumum backoff 5s and maximum backoff 1m0s...
2020/07/29 18:49:33 Created topic "test-topic"
2020/07/29 18:49:34 Created subscription "test-subscription"
2020/07/29 18:49:34 Published message
2020/07/29 18:49:36 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:49:45 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:49:56 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:50:06 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:50:17 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:50:30 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:50:35 Deleted subscription "test-subscription"
2020/07/29 18:50:35 Deleted topic test-topic
```

whereas if I run it with `MinimumBackoff` and `MaximumBackoff` of 1s and 2s, respectively, I get

```
> go run main.go --minimumBackoff=1s --maximumBackoff=2s
2020/07/29 18:50:42 Running with minumum backoff 1s and maximum backoff 2s...
2020/07/29 18:51:11 Created topic "test-topic"
2020/07/29 18:51:12 Created subscription "test-subscription"
2020/07/29 18:51:12 Published message
2020/07/29 18:51:15 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:18 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:21 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:25 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:28 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:31 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:35 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:38 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:40 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:44 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:47 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:50 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:52 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:54 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:51:57 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:52:00 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:52:03 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:52:06 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:52:09 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:52:12 Nacking message: Hello, world!
2020/07/29 18:52:13 Deleted subscription "test-subscription"
2020/07/29 18:52:13 Deleted topic test-topic
```

It seems like in the latter example, the time between nacks is pretty consistently ~3s, which presumably represents a "best effort" to do it in the `MaximumBackoff` of 2s? What is still not clear to me is whether there is any randomization, whether there is a multiplier (from the first example, it doesn't seem like the time between retries is getting twice as long every time), and whether there is an equivalent of the `MaxElapsedTime` beyond which there are no more retries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retry policy fields for minimum backoff and maximum backoff are similar to InitialInterval and MaxInterval in your example above. Cloud Pub/Sub uses a similar formula as you mentioned to compute the exponential delay. This includes randomization as well.

Beyond MaxInterval, every subsequent retry would have an added delay of MaxInterval. If you want to stop the retries after a certain number of attempts, we recommend using [Dead Letter Queues](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/dead-letter-topics).

Comment: Cool, I guess my next question is: what are the `Multiplier` and `RandomizationFactor` values in `RetryPolicy`'s implementation? In the first example, the time between nacks seems to increase only very slowly, suggesting that the `Multiplier` is close to 1.

Comment: These are system internal details and subjected to change over time. We do not recommend users depending on them.

Comment: @MaheshGattani That answer is really annoying. We as developers need to understand how the broker system we are using is going to behave. Understanding the backoff time distribution function is important. Changing whatever you want over time is fine as long as you share the information with your clients.